# thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4 sec:authorize does not work

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf

Hi i am working on springboot project and I added thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4 to my project . Actually it had been working for a long time but know it is not working.not working part is sec:authorize="hasRole('NORMAL')" code shown below

```
                <p>Kontrol Paneli</p>
                <span sec:authentication="name">Bob</span>
                Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities">[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]</span> |
                <p sec:authorize="!hasRole('NORMAL')">I am here</p>
                <p sec:authorize="!hasRole('ADMIN')">I am here</p>
            </a></li>
```

And result is [image]

as you see sec:authorize does not care which role user has.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found a solution , cause is springboot version . I am not using release version so that my project does not works as I desired . To prevent your project errors like that you have to use release version especially on production.

Thanks